# Perl: stop a command started using perl "system" in windows

Tags: windows, perl, command, system

in Perl, I started two commands in two different windows command line (Cmd) , as follow:

```
system("start $cmd1");
system("start $cmd2");
```

Basically, both commands continue running until I stop them using "CTRL+C".

My question is :

**How to send "CTR+C" to each Cmd line (or command) ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating two detached processes. See the code below: `

```
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

    sub ErrorReport{
        print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
    }

    Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
                                "C:\\winnt\\system32\\notepad.exe",
                                "notepad temp.txt",
                                0,
                                DETACHED_PROCESS,
                                ".")|| die ErrorReport();

    $ProcessObj->Suspend();
    $ProcessObj->Resume();
    $ProcessObj->Wait(INFINITE);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
my $pid = system(1, $cmd1);

# One of the following:
kill(INT  => $pid);  # Sends Ctrl-C
kill(TERM => $pid);  # Sends Ctrl-Break
kill(KILL => $pid);  # Calls TerminateProcess($handle, 9)

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: Under what circumstances will `system` return a process ID?

Comment: You can also use `open()` for something similar. If you `open()` an exec pipe, it returns a pid.

Comment: is killing the process "proper" and safe ?  is there any other safe ways of doing it ?